# Nagios Plugins Configure Flags

Tags: postgresql, nagios

For the life of me I can't find the configure flags for the Nagios Plugins. check_pgsql isn't compiling because it says it can't find the postgresql libraries, but I know exactly where they are on my server.

Comment: Which distro are you running? Post the full messages when compiling `check_pgsql`.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the development libraries installed, not just the runtime libraries?

On a RHEL/CentOS box, I see:

```
postgresql-devel.i386 : PostgreSQL development header files and libraries.
postgresql-libs.i386 : The shared libraries required for any PostgreSQL clients.
```

To build your own clients, you will most likely need to have postgresql-devel installed.  To run it, you'll need the postgresql-libs package.  Other Linuxes will have their own naming conventions if they split the runtime libraries from the development libraries, assuming you're using Linux.

Comment: +1 when you compile something that depends on another library you often need the source for that library too. if all fails you should be able to download the source of postgresql and set a /.configure flag to set the directory it looks in for the source files.

Comment: I compiled Postgresql 9 from source, and I know where the libraries are. For some reason when I go to compile the Nagios Plugins, it doesn't find them. Like I said. I can't find a configure flag to tell it where to find them.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a flag you can pass to configure for this, but inside the script it uses a variable called PGSQL to store its hard-coded assumptions on where to find postgresql. Running configure like this let me change the path and build check_pgsql.

```
PGSQL=/usr/pgsql-9.3 ./configure --therestofyourflagshere
```